# Do i have to delete wchar_t that i allocated with new?

Tags: c++

Lets say i have a class like this:

```
class LolClass {
    LPWSTR* stuff;
    LolClass::LolClass(LPWCHAR lols) {
        stuff = new LPWSTR[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            stuff[i] = new wchar_t[wcslen(lols)+1];
            wcsncpy(stuffs[i], lols, wcslen(lols)+1);
        }
    }
    LolClass::~LolClass() {
        delete[] stuff;
    }
}
```

so if i call

```
LolClass* veryfunny = new LolClass(L"lol!");
```

it would make me 100 lol's, problem is when i call

```
delete veryfunny;
```

it deletes the pointer array but not the individual wchar_t's, if i try and loop through the wchar_t's and delete them then i just crash and i dont know what to do since i know for fact that they are still there even after i delete veryfunny (i checked by passing one of the pointers outside the class)

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "crash"? any report we could see?

Comment: You should be looping through and `delete[] stuff[i]`, followed by `delete[] stuff`. Each `new[]` gets a `delete[]`.

Comment: You should call delete [] stuff[i] for all elements in loop, otherwise you would get memory leak

Comment: It goes something along the lines of "Debug Assertion Failed" ... "Line 52" ( ) ... "_Block_type_is_valid(pHead->nBlockUse)"

Comment: The first thing you should do when getting a crash is to run your program in a debugger. This will help you find the location of the crash, and also let you examine variables to help you find the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 6):

If you call

```
LolClass* veryfunny = new LolClass(L"lol!");
```

then you will eventually need to call:

```
delete veryfunny;
```

But for arrays, you need `delete[]`: `stuff[i] = new wchar_t[n]; delete [] stuff[i];`

In your code, you need to first loop over `stuff` and `delete[]` the elements, and then `delete[]` the array `stuff` itself.

Or just use a `std::vector<std::wstring>`.

---

*Update:* From what I understand, you're not actually worried about deleting `*veryfunny`, but rather about how to write a correct destructor for `LolClass`. Note that the destructor also gets invoked for global and automatic objects, e.g. `{ LolClass x(L"hello"); } /* boom */`, so it doesn't really matter *how* you instantiate an object for `LolClass`. You have to get the class right in any case.

Comment: Yes, the vector of strings (as well as `veryfunny` not being a pointer at all) is the sensible solution.

Comment: yea but thats the problem when i add a deconstructor like this: LolClass::~LolClass() {if (!Count) then return; for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {delete[] stuff[i];} delete[] stuff;} then i crash (i also have a counter int in my actual class)

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp: Are you sure that `Count` is always the same as `100`?

Comment: yes im sure, i checked that i have at least one stuff created, tried to delete it and results in crash

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp: Not just one, but all 100? Here's an idea: say `stuff = new LPWSTR[100]();`, with the extra parentheses. That will null-initialize all pointers, so that you can safely call `delete[]` even if you didn't get to allocate anything.

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp: Post the code that doesn't work and we'll help you fix it. There are a lot of things you could have done wrong and it's hard for us to figure out which of them is your issue. But yes, if you `new` it, you must `delete` it. If you `new[]` it, you must `delete[]` it.

Comment: 1) If a new entry is added to the directory between the two `do` loops, your code blows up. 2) I don't think you allocate enough memory for each full name -- you copy one more byte than you allocate.

Comment: 1) if the directory gets modified then yea but i'll figure out what to do about that later 2) i write over the null terminator of the path so it should be the exact amount i need.. anyway rest of the class works fine for now, just deleting it is a problem.

Answer (score -1):

David Schwartz wins after all, the wchar's didnt let themselves be deleted because they werent null terminated

Comment: That has **nothing** to do with memory allocation at all! That's very simply the fact that you mustn't call `wsclen` on a pointer that doesn't point to a null-terminated sequence of characters.